# ComObject Excel.Application without Office Suite

Tags: excel, powershell, ms-office, powershell-2.0

I need to read an Excel file from Powershell.
I am using this object:

```
$objExcel=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
```

It is working fine on a machine with an Office installation but if Office is not installed, I get this error:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

Is there some *runtime environment* for Office to use?

Answer (score 4):

There's no "runtime" for Excel that you can use without obtaining a proper license for Excel (and installing Excel on the machine). *If you were trying to do this on a Server OS with multiple users, you'd need to consider special licensing there too (as a single Excel license wouldn't cover multiple users more than likely).*

You might consider using the [OpenXML SDK for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx) as a way of performing some common actions within an Excel file like documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850837%28v=office.15%29.aspx). As it's a .NET library, you would be able to use it from within PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

> **Warning:** Excel Viewer is retired.

No runtime, like Access.

There is a viewer, if that's any help.

> **Overview**
>
> With Excel Viewer, you can open, view, and print Excel workbooks, even if you don't have Excel installed. You can also copy
> data from Excel Viewer to another program. However, you cannot edit
> data, save a workbook, or create a new workbook.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of COM it is possible to use Active X Data Objects (ADO) e.g.

```
$strFileName = "C:\Data\scriptingGuys\Servers.xls"
$strSheetName = 'ServerList$'
$strProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
$strDataSource = "Data Source = $strFileName"
$strExtend = "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
$strQuery = "Select * from [$strSheetName]"

$objConn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("$strProvider;$strDataSource;$strExtend")
$sqlCommand = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($strQuery)
$sqlCommand.Connection = $objConn
$objConn.open()

$DataReader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

While($DataReader.read())
{
 $ComputerName = $DataReader[0].Tostring() 
 "Querying $computerName ..."
 Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Bios -computername $ComputerName
}  
$dataReader.close()
$objConn.close()
```

Source: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/09/11/how-can-i-read-from-excel-without-using-excel.aspx